# How can I change the background color of a listview item at runtime after it has been populated (vs 2012)?

Tags: listview, visual-studio-2012, listviewitem

I have a listview box in my VS2012 express application.  The list is already populated, now I would like to search and highlight certain items in said list during runtime after the "Search" Command button has been pressed.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't do that in the OnItemDataBound event, try using the OnPreRender event to loop through all items and modify them/their contents through the Items collection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx.

If client-side is OK - jQuery is your friend. The addClass("newClass") method is very useful for adding styling. You can later remove it through removeClass("classToRemvoe") method.